# How to count number of records found in a database table?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, database

I am new to wordpress development & tried to learning plugin development.I have created a custom table from which i want to show the number of records found.I have tried the below code but it always shows 1 as a result irrespective of number of rows in a table.

```
//To show number of rows in table
    function DB_Tables_Rows()
    {
      global $wpdb;
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mydata';
     $count_query = "select count(*) from $table_name";
         $num = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);

         $num = $wpdb->num_rows;

        echo  $wpdb->num_rows . 'Rows Found';


    }
```

Comment: `get_var` already returns count. Check dumping `$num` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you directly echo the $num as it will contain the count of rows already...Here's the edited part..

```
//To show number of rows in table
  function DB_Tables_Rows()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mydata';
    $count_query = "select count(*) from $table_name";
    $num = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);

    echo  $num . 'Rows Found';


}
```

Comment: Old thread.  There is a flaw in this.  If it is an empty table it will return '1' as that single row will have the value 0 being the count.

Comment: @Steve This ain't true. It's taking the count value... not counting the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

#### WAY #1

You can use the WordPress way using [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mydata';
$my_query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
echo $my_query->num_rows;
```

The codex says:

> Since this function uses the `$wpdb->query()` function all the class
>   variables are properly set. The results count for a '`SELECT`' query
>   will be stored in `$wpdb->num_rows`.

#### WAY #2

It can also be count by PHP way. Just use your generic query, and use the PHP `count()` function.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mydata';
$my_query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
$num_rows = count( $my_query ); //PHP count()
echo $num_rows;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Though it's my favorite, but as @MarkKaplun says:

> *there is a huge performance difference between counting the size of an
>   array in PHP, and letting mysql count the rows for you. You are
>   unlikely to notice it on small data, but for big tables you will.*

So I'd also love to stick with the `$wpdb` way. <3

Comment: ,thanks for quick response butI have 12 rows in a table but first code is showing 0 as result & the second code which is MySQL way is showing warning                                         mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/u168837564/public_html/wp-content/plugins/DB_Tables/DB_Tables.php on line 136

Comment: there is a huge performance difference between counting the size of an array in PHP, and letting mysql count the rows for you. You are unlikely to notice it on small data, but for big tables you will.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun I's unaware about it. And now I posted my answer after some searching. My luck that it was wrong first time, because that triggered me to learn the whole. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam, np ;) just to write down the reason there is a difference, it is related to the cost of finding and transferring the info from the DB to the PHP code. When you query for only the number of rows there is much less communication overhead. (and of course the DB might have the rows number cached as part of its data structure and therefor it requires almost zero work to find it)